# React - initialize a plugin inside a component (didMount?)

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a jcarousel plugin and it's not initializing correctly. When I initialize it from my main.js document.ready, it requires a page refresh when I click to the page that has the carousel.

Is there a 'correct' method for initializing plugins inside components?

For example... something like this?:

```
componentDidMOunt: function() {
  $('.jcaoursel').jcarousel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do initialization of plugins in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` if the element that the plugin applies to changes. I would also use refs and ReactDOM to refer to the specific div that you want to apply the plugin to. Using `.jcarousel` would re-initialize the plugin on all elements with that class on the entire app, which may not be what you want in the long run.

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.carousel)).jcarousel();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div ref="carousel"></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You don't need `findDOMNode` in your example, can just do `this.refs.carousel` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work. Is it maybe because the div in question hasn't rendered yet so it tries to initialize the plugin on a missing element? I tried it in componentDidMount... willMount... everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  $('.jcaoursel').jcarousel();
}
```

inside the component that renders the div with the carousel class. If not jquery might not find your selector because it may not have been rendered yet into the DOM.